# launchctl sub commands load and unload says its legacy sub commands on mac os x 10.10. how to replace this sub commands with other

Tags: macos, launchd

I have found that the launchctl sub commands like load/ unload listed in legacy sub commands on mac os x 10.10.

So my question is how to launchctl to load/unload demons present at /Library/LaunchDaemons/

I visited the [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/33259).

using this I do `sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mydemo.com`

and found that service load successfully only if plist's permission is proper.

but not able to unload it with the help of non legacy commands.

I found when I try using command  `sudo launchctl unbootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mydemo.com` it shows message saying "Command is not yet implemented".

NOTE: load/ unload still works.

Answer (score 1):

The counterpart of `bootstrap` is **`bootout`**:

```
sudo launchctl bootout system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mydemo.service.plist
```

Comment: Note that `bootout` was added in 10.11 El Capitan. As far as I can tell, 10.10 doesn't have a modern replacement for `unload`.